# Fullcalendar won't enter data from mysql table into the calendar

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying get Fullcalendar to take information from a mysql table and enter the informtion into the calendar.  The calendar appears, but none of the information from the table is on the calendar.

Here is my code.

**calendar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>

    body {
            margin-top: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            }

    #loading {
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            right: 5px;
            }

    #calendar {
            width: 900px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            }
</style>

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery/ui.core.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery/ui.draggable.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: "json-events.php",
        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
        alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
           '(should probably update your database)');
     },

    loading: function(bool) {
        if (bool) $('#loading').show();
        else $('#loading').hide();
    }

});

});

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id='loading' style='display:none'>loading...</div>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
    <p>json_events.php needs to be running in the same directory.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**json_events.php**

```
<?php

    include("dbstuff.inc");

    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

    $sql= "SELECT id, title, description, url, email, Stime, Etime, eventDate, DATE_FORMAT(eventDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i' ) AS startDate
        FROM events
        ORDER BY startDate DESC";
    $check = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $events = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check)) {
        $eventArray['id'] = $row['id'];   
        $eventArray['title'] = $row['title'];
        $eventArray['description'] = $row['description'];
        $eventArray['url'] = $row['url'];
        $eventArray['email'] = $row['email'];
        $eventArray['startTime'] = $row['Stime'];
        $eventArray['EndTime'] = $row['Etime'];   
        $eventArray['title'] =  $row['Stime'] . " " . $row['title'];
        $eventArray['start'] = $row['startDate'];
        $eventsArray['allDay'] = "";
        $events[] = $eventArray;
}
echo json_encode($events);

?>
```

This is the data from MySQL file

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "07:00:00 test1",
        "description": "werewr",
        "url": "http://www.nba.com",
        "email": "someone@host.com",
        "startTime": "07:00:00",
        "EndTime": "09:00:00",
        "start": "2013-04-22T00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "11:00:00 test2",
        "description": "hello",
        "url": "http://www.nba.com",
        "email": "someone@host.com",
        "startTime": "11:00:00",
        "EndTime": "13:00:00",
        "start": "2013-04-15T00:00"
    }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

you have events: "json-events.php" and your php file it's json_events.php